# Solving the following system of equations $3o+2a+b=15$, $5o+7a+2b=44$, $o+3a+5b=26$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm attempting to solve a word problem that goes like this:
"A box containing 3 oranges, 2 apples and one banana weighs 15 unites. Another box containing 5, apples 7 oranges and 2 banans weighs 44 units. Third box containing an orange, 3 apples and 5 banans weighs 26".

So $o, a, b$ are orange, apple and banana weighs respectively

$3o+2a+b=15$, EQ1

$5o+7a+2b=44$, EQ2

$o+3a+5b=26$ EQ3

I'll do this via elimination.

EQ3' = 3(EQ3) - EQ1 and EQ2' = 3(EQ2) - 5(EQ1) give:

$7a + 14b = 78$, EQ2

$11a + b = 57$ EQ3

EQ3 can be rearranged $b=57-11a$ and i plug this in to get:

$7a + 14(57-11a) = 78 \therefore 7a+ 798 - 154a = 78 \therefore -147a = -720$

Now when i perform the final step and divide out the coefficient I get a long rational number that starts with $5.8$. Where did i make a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that the first step $3EQ_3-EQ_1$ leads to

$$7a + 14b = 63$$

you didn't subtract $15$ from $78$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve using linear algebra. The problem creates the augmented matrix $$\left[\begin{array}{c c c | c}3 &2  &1 &15\\ 5 &7  &2&44 \\ 1 &3  &5&26 \end{array}\right]$$
Or if you would like $$\begin{bmatrix}3 &2  &1 \\ 5 &7  &2 \\ 1 &3  &5 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}o\\ a\\ b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}15\\ 44\\ 26\end{bmatrix}$$

You can either RREF (row reduce) the augmented matrix to solve it, see this link:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/AugmentedMatrix.aspx

Or you can use a TI graphing calculator to quickly solve it, see here:
https://www.ccps.org/site/handlers/filedownload.ashx?moduleinstanceid=4330&dataid=2830&FileName=Solving%20Matrices%20on%20the%20Calculator.pdf

Comment: I cleaned up your MathJax, since it was quite messy.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I could not find out how to make a clean augmented matrix.

Comment: Now you know :)